# How to create pairs of nodes in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame in Spark and Scala:

```
group   nodeId   date
1       1        2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z
1       2        2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z
1       3        2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z
2       1        2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z
2       2        2016-10-12T12:35:00.000Z
```

I need to group records by `group`, sort them in ascending order by `date` and make pairs of sequential `nodeId`. Also, `date` should be converted to Unix epoch.

This can be better explained with the expected output:

```
group   nodeId_1   nodeId_2   date
1       2          3          2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z
1       3          1          2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z
2       1          2          2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z
```

This is what I did so far:

```
df
  .groupBy("group")
  .agg($"nodeId",$"date")
  .orderBy(asc("date"))
```

But I don't know how to create pairs of `nodeId`.

Comment: You can get all pairs of nodeId with a cross join: df.crossJoin(df.select("nodeId"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be benefited by using `Window` function with `lead` inbuilt function to create the pairs and `to_utc_timestamp` inbuilt function to convert the date to epoch date. Finally you have to `filter` the unpaired rows as you don't require them in the output.

Following is the program of above explanation. I have used comments for clarity

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("date")    //defining window function grouping by group and ordering by date

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("date", to_utc_timestamp(col("date"), "Asia/Kathmandu"))     //converting the date to epoch datetime you can choose other timezone as required
  .withColumn("nodeId_2", lead("nodeId", 1).over(windowSpec))  //using window for creating pairs
    .filter(col("nodeId_2").isNotNull)                   //filtering out the unpaired rows
    .select(col("group"), col("nodeId").as("nodeId_1"), col("nodeId_2"), col("date"))  //selecting as required final dataframe
  .show(false)
```

You should get the final `dataframe` as required

```
+-----+--------+--------+-------------------+
|group|nodeId_1|nodeId_2|date               |
+-----+--------+--------+-------------------+
|1    |2       |3       |2016-10-12 12:00:00|
|1    |3       |1       |2016-10-12 12:05:00|
|2    |1       |2       |2016-10-12 12:30:00|
+-----+--------+--------+-------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Note** *to get the correct epoch date I have used `Asia/Kathmandu` as timezone*.

Comment: Why do you order by `date` (without converting `date` to a timestamp)?

Comment: `.withColumn("date", to_utc_timestamp(col("date"), "Asia/Kathmandu"))` has already converted the date to timestamp and after that only I used window function so the order happened on timestamp date. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can use a self-join on `group` and a `<` inequality condition on `nodeId`:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, "2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z"),
  (1, 2, "2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z"),
  (1, 3, "2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z"),
  (2, 1, "2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z"),
  (2, 2, "2016-10-12T12:35:00.000Z")
).toDF("group", "nodeId", "date")

df.as("df1").join(
  df.as("df2"),
  $"df1.group" === $"df2.group" && $"df1.nodeId" < $"df2.nodeId"
).select(
  $"df1.group", $"df1.nodeId", $"df2.nodeId",
  when($"df1.date" < $"df2.date", $"df1.date").otherwise($"df2.date").as("date")
)

// +-----+------+------+------------------------+
// |group|nodeId|nodeId|date                    |
// +-----+------+------+------------------------+
// |1    |1     |3     |2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z|
// |1    |1     |2     |2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z|
// |1    |2     |3     |2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z|
// |2    |1     |2     |2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z|
// +-----+------+------+------------------------+
```

Comment: It does not coincide with the expected outputs.

Comment: I thought you were to pair nodes within individual groups.  If not, what's your criteria for picking node pair (1, 2) from group 2 instead of from group 1 (or even across the two groups)?